# Managing paragraph Tab settings in a tRichEdit - Delphi

Tags: delphi, richedit

I am working with a tRichEdit component  and using a tSpinedit to determine tab spacings using the trichedit.oncreate event to generate an array of tab positions to begin with.  This is working fine and each new paragraph I generate uses the defined tab spacing. However, when using the SpinEdit1 Change event, I can change the tab spacing for the paragraph of text in which the cursor is placed, but it is not performing across the whole richedit text.

Is there a way to apply new tabstop settings across all of the paragraphs in a richedit document?

When I change the tab settings using tForm1.SpinEdit1Change, the tabs change for the current paragraph and subsequent ones, but previous paragraphs remain as they were. Is there a way to iterate through the paragraphs in the richedit1 content to change all of them in a 'for' loop?  I have not found any array or list in the properties. Is there a property for setting the tabs globally at runtime or another approach that will accomplish this?

Comment: The edit makes it much better. I've retracted my close vote. Looks like @TomBrunberg answered that question about all paragraphs below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select all paragraphs (from the very beginning to the end of the document) before setting the tab positions. You can select all paragraphs either manually, or programmatically with

```
RichEdit1.SelectAll;
```

Ref. documentation:
[Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Paragraph](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Paragraph)

> Paragraph formatting information includes alignment, indentation,
>   numbering, and tabs.
>
> Paragraph is a read-only property, because a TCustomRichEdit object
>   has only one TParaAttributes object, which cannot be changed. The
>   attributes of the current paragraphs, however, can be changed, by
>   setting the properties of the TParaAttributes object.
>
> The current paragraphs are the **paragraphs that contain the selected
>   text**. If no text is selected, the current paragraph is the one
>   containing the cursor.